# How to remove simple product form cart in magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, cart

I need to **remove** **simple product** from cart.

Remove item option available only for **configurable product**

```
<a href="#"
   title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Remove item')); ?>"
   class="action action-delete btn-remove btn-remove2 remove-btn"
   data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getDeletePostJson(); ?>'>
   <i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <?php /* <span>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified * / echo __('Remove item')?>
    </span> */ ?>
</a>
```

Above code is working for **configurable product**

1. How to remove simple product from cart?

Answer (score 0):

Remove Item its available for Simple Products on cart Page By Default for same version provided by you